# Performing an action when a listpreference option is selected

Tags: android, multithreading, preferences

Sorry I had to rephrase my question, I have a list preference with some option

[image]

I want to change the value of a variable depending on the option selected. I have no idea how to get the selected index or where to start from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, start by throwing out that code you posted. :) You don't want to use a thread for scheduled updates, you want to use the [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

The reason for this is that Android might kill your running app at any time. When an alarm fires it will wake up your app as needed, starting it from scratch if necessary so that it can run.

Comment: The thread is actually running inside a service, wouldn't that solve the problem?

Comment: @Amanni: No, it would not solve the problem. If anything, it makes it worse. Do not waste RAM by keeping a process around simply to watch the clock tick by. Please use `AlarmManager`.

Comment: thanks, I'm working it atm. Any ideas on how to trigger an action when an item is selected in listprefrence

Comment: Try an OnPreferenceChangeListener: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html You should post a new question rather than edit an old, answered one into a new one. Keeping a record of your old question helps other people who may have similar questions later.

Comment: I will remember that, I know about the listner, what i'm trying to figure out is how to get the selected item in an if/else or switch/case to I can get the app to do something when they ares selected

Comment: CommonsWare, I've been looking through the Alarm Manager and it does seem better than using a service. Can you give link to a tutorial of a repeated Alarm not a one-shot and is it possible I just execute a method rather than fire an intent?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the Alarmmanager now and it's much better, one thing though. I'm using my alarm manager to trigger a Service which does the update. I want to know if the alarmmanager stops the service after it has performed its task